# what is the best approach for extracting a value from multiple text files and then displaying them on a web page using perl or php or both?

Tags: php, perl

I have multiple hidden files in a directory and would like to open and/or cat each one of them, extract each value and display on a web page.
Each file has a value already embedded in a format I need. So no need to parse anything except grab the value from the file.

I would like your input on a good programmatic approach to doing this either using perl or php. Would it be best to do it all in php or use both? How would you do it? Thanks for your input.

The files are named like so:

```
.stat_run_dir
.stat_file_sent.domain1
.stat_file_sent.domain2
```

Values would look like this respectively:

```
/absolute/path/category/testfeed_dom_2010120806.abc
domain1_sub.dat.2010120804.abc
domain2_sub.dat.2010120805.abc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, sending the contents of a file to the browser is one line:

```
<?php readfile('.stat_run_dir'); ?>
```

You can read an entire file into a variable just as easily:

```
<?php
    $text = file_get_contents('.stat_file_sent.domain1');
    echo $text;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for your help. if I'm doing (3) files. should i declare $text2, $text3, etc? and echo each? or is there a better way to loop through all three and stuff each in its own variable? thx.

Comment: Well, you could loop. Put the file names in an array. Maybe there's a pattern to the names so you don't even have to create the array. Maybe you can just read them from a directory. You know these things, I don't. The language manual for whatever language you choose should cover whatever you need.

Comment: yeah, there would be a pattern, all prefixed with '.stat_'  so maybe I can loop through that .stat_* and dump into an array. i will stick with doing all this in php if i can.

Answer (score 2):

I would go by dirty solution, use `grep` instead

```
system('grep YOUR_MATCHING_PATTERN YOUR_TARGET_FILES');
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer "Perl or PHP", the answer is (all other things being equal) whichever one you're most comfortable in, especially - in case of web pages - in terms of debugging.

In Perl, to get the values is trivial:

```
use File::Slurp;
my %file_contents;
my @files = glob(".stat_*");
foreach my $file (@files) {
    $file_contents{$file} = File::Slurp::read_file($file);
}
```

Displaying on web page depends on what you have available (ideally, a templating module which works pretty much the same way PHP code does, e.g. EmbPerl, HTML::Template etc...). Worst case scenario, do a simple CGI.pm page, though templating stuff is way easier.

An EmbPerl example would be (in the absence of example of how you want to print, I chose something):

```
[$ foreach $file @files $]
[+ $file +] : [+ $file_contents{$file} +]<br>
[$ endforeach $]
```

Comment: thanks for your input. More comfortable with perl, which I use sparingly, but understand more than php, but the emphasis of the task was to create a web page. I tried the slurp, works pretty well.